# Why is the Search Crawler visiting spending so much time on apparently empty sites?

Tags: 2007, search

I am currently capturing usage data for the site collections in my organisations MOSS 2007 deployment and I have noticed some oddities in the search crawlers behavior.

Part of the data being captured is Site Size, Distict users per day over 30 days and yesterday and crawler hits on the site collection over 30 days and per day. Some very busy sites with gigabytes of stored data accessed daily (the main intranet portal for example) recieve only a single daily hit on average from the search crawler whilst an out-of-date meeting space with no content on it and no visitors (currently scheduled for deletion) recieved 11 crawler hits yesterday and an almost unused teamsite whose only traffic was me checking the usage stats recieved 126 hits.

Can someone with a decent understanding of Search in MOSS 2007 do me a favour and explain what is happening here and why please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be a number of things!

the search crawl is behaving as it should! ;)

now there is a difference with looking up (crawling) to actually indexing. If somthing has changed than an index would be performed and depending on the type would issue a full crawl or a partial crawl.

so what me need to know is what is the search crawl shedule look like? are you running full crawls on the weekend? are partial crawls set daily out of hours? also like to know when are these crawls occuring and where/how are you capturing usage data???

just because no one visits the empty site which you have doesnt mean the search service is not going to crawl that area!

are you getting the data from the managed search service application?

it could be that on the busy sites people are veiwing rather than adding or ammending?

1) where are you getting data from?

2) what is you search config like for partial and full crawls?

3) when is the crawls occuring on your data and over how many days?

so lets explain a possible senario ;)

the usage stats with 126 hits! i presum thats a site you made to store the stats. If so then those stats are going to be updated or added are they not?? if so then this would issue a schedueld task in the timer service for a crawl. The search crawl would then save this url or data in a temp location and it would check against the database where it stores the full crawl log to check against to see any changes, if so it would update accordingly (partial crawl).

the main busy site (intranet), you need to know if this has the correct search topology on this site location for incremental crawls and full crawls. 1 hit is very odd unless its running very frequent?

the outdated meeting space could be updating due to a list.update or web.update being called even tho nothing was updated??

without looking at the log you could be guessing all day! to look at the log you need to go to this locatiom:

> 1 Open the administration page for the Shared Services Provider (SSP).
>
> 2 To open the administration page for the SSP, do the following:
>
> 3 On the top navigation bar, click Application Management.
>
> 4 On the Application Management page, in the Office SharePoint Server Shared Services section, click Create or configure this farm’s
>   shared services.
>
> 5 On the Manage this Farm’s Shared Services page, click the SSP whose administration page you want to open.
>
> 6 On the Shared Services Administration Home page, in the Search
>   section, click Search settings.
>
> 7 On the Configure Search Settings page, in the Crawl Settings section,
>   click Crawl logs.
>
> 8 On the Crawl Log page, on the left navigation bar, you can click
>   either View by hostname, by which you can find the URLs that begin
>   with a specific hostname and path, or View by URL, by which you can
>   filter the crawl log.

why look at the log?

> The crawl log tracks information about the status of crawled content.
>   This log allows you to verify whether crawled content was added to the
>   index successfully, whether it was excluded because of a crawl rule,
>   or whether indexing failed because of an error. Additional information
>   about the crawled content is also logged, including the time of the
>   last successful crawl, the content source (there could be more than
>   one), the content access account used, and whether any crawl rules
>   were applied.

what to filter on:

> All integer properties (such as startAt, TotalEntries, and MessageId)
>
> Log time
>
> Message type
>
> URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms553190%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263379%28v=office.12%29.aspx

dive in deep with the working out of how search service works and why:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/228.search-architecture-in-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/10/30/sp2010-search-explained-crawling.aspx